# Download system image for android emulator with one of the prevous build versions

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop

I need to run in emulator image for Nexus 6 android 5.0 build LRX21O. When im downloading system image (using android studio) from android-21 its automatically downloading newest build which is LSY66K and there is no possibility to select which build i want to use.

Is there any way to run build downloaded from

https://developers.google.com/android/images

inside emulator?

When im replacing system.img and userdata.img inside Sdk/system-images/android-21/default-x86_64 image does not want to start,

Is there any way to run this image in emulator?

If no, could some1 share emulator image android 21 5.0 LRX21O?

Best regards, K